# HTML/JavaScript and ActroJS communcation in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, pdf, pdfium

All right, it's about to get all weeeeeird up in here.

My goal: I want to push messages back and forth between AcroJS running in a PDF form and regular JS running in an HTML DOM that wraps it, all of which lives in an iframe. I don't control the creation of the PDF documents, but I can patch some AcroJS in using iTextSharp, which seems to be working so far.

My problem: In Chrome (using built-in PDF support/no Adobe plugin) some of the APIs are missing. The embed tag has the postMessage method on it, as I would expect (and as it does in browsers using Adobe's PDF plugin), but on the actual PDF side, the document doesn't have a hostingContainer property, so I can't wire up methods to receive events sent via postMessage.

My question: Does Chrome have a different way of registering that handler? Is it just missing, as I've heard some functionality is? If so, is the postMessage method on the other tag a red herring? I'm kinda baffled and so far haven't been able to find any kind of programming reference *except* Adobe's, which apparently doesn't completely cover Chrome.

Comment: Have you tried to use a server as a relay? So set up a connection with the server (WebSocket / long polling / whatever) in your web app, and use the scripting API in the PDF file to send / retrieve data from the server. It's a bit clumsy, but perhaps an option if you don't have any other alternatives.

Comment: I haven't - is that an option? Ultimately, I'm trying to get to the server - the catch is that, at least in Adobe PDF, it doesn't look like you can use any of the web request functions from within a document, but instead have to do this craziness: http://asserttrue.blogspot.com/2010/07/doing-ajax-from-acrobat-tips-tricks-and.html ... at which point we might be better off ditching PDF entirely. =/

It seems like it's at least intended to work, since postMessage is part of the PDF object. I wonder if there's any documentation for Chrome's specific JavaScript APIs anywhere.

Comment: Yes, that "craziness" is what I'm referring to. In Chrome, the PDF viewer is implemented as an extension that in turn loads a plugin. The `<embed>` tag is a kind of `<iframe>`. That's probably why there is a `postMessage` method on it. If possible, I suggest to use just HTML/CSS/JS instead of PDFs if you want a platform-independent form.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize postMessage was a standard thing, but there it is. That's pretty handy, actually. As far as using HTML/CSS/JS instead of PDFs, that might be possible with an adapter like PDF.js (and is something I'll be looking into if this doesn't play out), or a conversion process, but the forms are provided by users/governments/etc and are natively PDF format.

Comment: PDF.js does not support form editing yet (https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/1459). But adding this feature is probably less fragile than trying to force PDFium to communicate with your web page. It's easier to customize PDF.js to do what you want than forcing PDF & Chrome to cooperate with your web app.

Comment: Everything I'm using is documented as features of PDF, even if they're missing from PDFium's implementation. Ultimately, my question is if they are, truly missing, or just implemented a different way. The PDF spec leaves them optional (and, actually, the reference implementation for Mac doesn't include them), and that might be all there is to it. I'm going ahead and opening an issue with the PDFium developers as well, though, just in case.

Comment: All right, as it turns out PDF.js does have some support for at least describing AcroForms annotations and they have a sample for using that data to put DOM fields on top of the form in an overlay. It's incomplete, but they seem to be open to pull requests to expand the annotation support. This looks like the direction I'll be heading.